# How does the particle in the box model relate to electron confinement in Quantum Dots

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-dots

To quote Wikapedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_dot

> Nanoscale semiconductor materials tightly confine either electrons or electron holes. The confinement is similar to a three-dimensional particle in a box model. The quantum dot absorption and emission features correspond to transitions between discrete quantum mechanically allowed energy levels in the box that are reminiscent of atomic spectra.

I understand the particle in a box model, in 1 dimension, but I'd like someone to clarify exactly how this relates to electron confinement in quantum dots. Do to the absorption and emission spectra correspond to different stationary states for the solution of the particle in the box model or in this case, a confined electron?

My analogy for the infinite square well was that of an object floating on a pocket of air with perfectly elastic bumpers, a bit like a 1 dimensional air hockey table, but how does this relate to a confined electron? Also what is an electron hole?

I apologise if my question does not make any sense, I am writing a brief research report on Quantum Dots, but I need it to relate to the material I have covered in QM 1, and I am trying to gain a better understanding of how this could be.